# Regarding SQL Server Identity Property for a column

Tags: sql-server

I have set Identity Property as (1001,1) to a column (ex:Employee Id) in table in SQL Server 2008, when I insert some records it starts generating as 1001,1002,1003. But when I delete a record of 1002, or totally , I want to set Identity Property to 1001 again. how to set Identity Property to initial value after deleting records, can Any body Help me..??

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

First link from google

is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/) (DBCC CHECKIDENT)

Are you sure this is what you want to do though ? Generally reseeding an identity should only be done if you have emptied the table.

Good description of three methods [here as well](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/24/sql-server-delete-truncate-and-reseed-identity/)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably a `RESEED`

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tablename, RESEED, _newStartingNumber_)
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing so you have to truncate your table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE yourtable
```

But this can be done only when there isn't any record in the table i.e. all records has been deleted.

Comment: @downvoter, can you explain why it is in the down vote category

Comment: One use case they give is deleting the single record with id 1002. `TRUNCATE` will delete all rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith Read my answer I am saying only use this when there is no records

Comment: @nrsharma , i have not down voted. but, the reason may be, truncate can be used even if records are present in the table

Comment: That isn't the situation described in the question though so this is irrelevant. `RESEED` is the correct answer though frankly the OP shouldn't bother even doing this.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM TableName` will just delete records, but the `seeding` will remain.  `Truncate Table TableName` name will reset the seeding and delete records.

However, you mention resetting based on the deletion of one record - can you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for Reply.. @christiandev, Actually I have deleted a record in middle , now I want to  reset Identity Property as per sequence for all the next records after deleted record. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME   
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TABLE_NAME,RESEED,new_reseedvalue)
```

or you can simply use:

```
 truncate table table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case (which i prefer) is to find `max([Employee Id])` and then insert data.

If you would like to reseed the table,you might want to look into:

[DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

To reset identity column value.